# Where and where-not to specify 3d model scaling?

Tags: android, scaling, arcore, sceneform

I need to understand better the scaling process for a **ARCore**'s **Sceneform** scene.

As far as I know, in order to scale a **Renderable**, we have three options:

1) doing it in the ***sfa(s) file(s)***, what maybe a good pre-requisite under a production workflow, but doesn't help me in trying to know the scaling process in **ARCore-Sceneform**, so I wish to focus in the next two options;

2) scale the model by means of  **AnchorNode**:

```
...
Anchor anchor = hitResult.createAnchor();
//
AnchorNode anchorNode = new AnchorNode(anchor);
anchorNode.setParent(_arFragment.getArSceneView().getScene());
anchorNode.setRenderable(_renderable);
anchorNode.setLocalScale(new Vector3(0.01f,0.01f,0.01f)); //m -> cm
...
```

3) scale it via **Node**:

```
...
Anchor anchor = hitResult.createAnchor();
//
AnchorNode anchorNode = new AnchorNode(anchor);
anchorNode.setParent(_arFragment.getArSceneView().getScene());
//
TransformableNode node = new TransformableNode(_arFragment.getTransformationSystem());
node.setParent(anchorNode);
node.setRenderable(_renderable); 
node.setLocalScale(new Vector3(0.01f,0.01f,0.01f)); //m -> cm
...
```

The case is that I'm not experimenting the same results whether I use **AnchorNode** that when using **Node**, as only the first of them is showing the correct (expected) scaling. How is it that?

In parallel, I don't know what is the correct order in the node calls to APIs, that is: setParent + setRenderable + setLocalScale, setRenderable + setParent + setLocalScale, ... Any help with this?

Thanks in advance for your time.